# onClick event is not triggered on TextInputEditText android

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-textinputedittext

I have the following TextInputEditText

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/from_textinput"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="@string/from"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGrey"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorDarkGrey"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="5dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="5dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="5dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="5dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="3dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/to_textinput"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/doNotDisturbCheckBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.openFromTimePickerClicked()}"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/from_textedit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="@{viewModel.doNotDisturbFrom}"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

the problem that onClick is not triggered on the first touch, it is only called when I press for the second time

the first click make it focus
the first click fire onClick

can anyone tell me how to fire click from the first time

Comment: try switching to `TextView`, since it is read-only anyway

Comment: That'll likely prevent the floating hint from working, as `TextInputLayout` is looking for specifically an `EditText`.

Comment: @MikeM. yes you are correct

Comment: @NathanHeadley there is no xml method onFocus

Comment: @NathanHeadley it show the following message --> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onFocusChanged' with parameter type lambda on com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from_textedit.setEnabled(true);
from_textedit.setTextIsSelectable(true);
from_textedit.setFocusable(false);
from_textedit.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
from_textedit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Edit Text is clicked");
    }
});
```